# Best way to manually move/rotate a physicsBody in SpriteKit iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, sprite-kit, skphysicsbody

What is the best way to manually move or rotate a physicsBody in SpriteKit? The move will be invoked when the user touches the screen.?

An important requirement is that the physicsBody must move to and stay in the new position/rotation until the touch has ended. That being said, simply applying an impulse will not suffice.

Help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

two ways you can rotate and move a body

1)

**ontouch for rotation**

sprite.physicsBody.allowsRotation=TRUE;

**ontouch for change x**

-(void)didSimulatePhysics
{

```
sprite.physicsBody.velocity=CGVectorMake(50, 0);
```

}

and second way you can do it by skAction but make sure your physics body is not dynamic

```
[SKAction moveBy:<#(CGVector)#> duration:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>];
[SKAction rotateByAngle:<#(CGFloat)#> duration:<#(NSTimeInterval)#>];
```

give a name to every action and remove it when a touch ended

Comment: Thanks. The SKAction way almost works as desired except making the body non-dynamic causes the body to defy gravity and stick in once place. The rotating body is to be an arm, attached to a torso with a pin joint, where the torso needs to be dynamic. So on touch, the arm will stick out. How can I get around this problem? @dragoneye

Comment: Also don't forget about `applyForce`, `applyTorque`

Comment: on touch set the physics body to nil and on touch up recreate physics body again

Comment: I tried but isn't ideal as it kills the body joints. Your help has given me a clearer direction to go in, thanks @dragoneye